# I want to include a manually typed image below an image when I click on a LinkedIn share button?

Tags: javascript

I have a LinkedIn share button, I am getting a popup like this. I want some message after the link, like we get in Facebook or Twitter. How could we do the same on LinkedIn?

http://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url=google.com&quote=YourarticleSummary

[image]

Comment: Did you check this? [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/share-on-linkedin?context=linkedin/consumer/context#create-a-text-share)

Comment: Yes. But how to implement that json into a linkedIn popup?

Comment: This is official [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/plugins/share-plugin) and it doesn't say anything about custom content. Probably not possible

Answer (score 0):

You have these options, you may not choose both:

- Share an image with LinkedIn Share API.
- Share a description with LinkedIn Share API.

I have talked with LinkedIn Support about this for two weeks, (*[Oh the humanity...](https://www.revoltlib.com/linkedin-social-share-url-broken-ticket.html)*), and I have been e-mailing the developers to fix this.  But, to no avail.

Let's also look at share previews for sites that each follow one of these rules: Wikipedia (has no image, has 1 description) and GitHub (has 1 image, has 1 description).

[image]
[image]

**Wikipedia:** [Description Text Shows (because no image is used)](https://www.linkedin.com/sharing/share-offsite/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.wikipedia.org%2F)
**GitHub:** [Image Shows (but the supplied description is not)](https://www.linkedin.com/sharing/share-offsite/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.github.com%2F)

I made a [test site, with only description,](https://www.revoltlib.com/linkedin-social-share-url-test.html) and it behaves according to the rule above-listed.  I'm well aware that the [Official Microsoft LinkedIn Share Documentation](https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/answer/46687/making-your-website-shareable-on-linkedin?lang=en) makes no mention whatsoever of this, but all direct experience seems to disagree.